# how to organise and maintain mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, branch, repository-design

At the moment I have 5 differently branded products with almost the same codebase (the differences are brand related) and all those products live in the separated mercurial branches.

Bug fixing and development is done in the `default` branch and all changes are transplanted to the branches with `hg transplant` command. This approach is working but number of the brands might be increased it'll take longer to keep all branches in up to date state.

I'm wondering if there is any other/easier way for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `transplant` in this case sounds like overkill.  You should simply be making the bugfix changes in the `default` branch and use `hg pull` (on the branded repositories) and merge the changes on all of the branded repositories.

`transplant` was added to Mercurial to allow for cherry-picking changesets that needed a special case to go backward in the normal flow of changesets (i.e. a *single* change introduced in the fork/branch needs to be spliced into the original repository)

Comment: I totally agree. I don't sure that I can take, let say, only 7 from 10 commits using hg pull.

Comment: @Dmytro I'm not sure I follow, it is possible to do an `hg pull` to a specific changeset (in the case where you may not want all of the changes in `default`). Use `hg incoming` to see the changes that would be pulled in, and then `hg pull -r X` (where "`X`" is the changeset you want to pull up to).